# mypy Incompatible default for argument

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.10

Given the following example

```
from typing import Any, Iterable, Callable, TypeVar, Tuple

from itertools import islice


T = TypeVar('T')

def take1(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[T,...]:  
    return tuple(islice(iterable, n))
    

def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[Any], container:Callable[[Iterable[Any]],T]=tuple) -> T:  
    return container(islice(iterable, n))
```

as is I get

```
test.py:12: error: Incompatible default for argument "container" (default has type "Type[Tuple[Any, ...]]", argument has type "Callable[[Iterable[Any]], T]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

As you can see *take2* is a more generalize version of *take1*, that by default is *take1* but if the user want to put the result into something else there isn't some throw away tuple in the middle by just providing the desired container directly. So for instance `"".join(take1(3,"abcdefg"))` is equivalent to `take2(3,"abcdefg","".join)` just that there isn't that throw away tuple that *take1* would make, which can be relevant in for example `sum(take1(10**10,itertools.count())` vs `take2(10**10,itertools.count(),sum)` (take1 will fail with a memory error here while take2 will succeed eventually)...

For that I think the hint I put there is perfectly adequate, but mypy doesn't like it.

**So, how can I type hint take2 so it pass the mypy test?** (beside `#type: ignore` I suppose) and still get an useful info when calling help on it

Comment: I made mypy happy using `tuple.__call__` but i dont think this is a good solution?

Comment: @YohannBoniface that is interesting, but I don't think is a good solution, also I don't like how it look when calling help on it with that `<method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x00007FFC917E9440>)` as opposed to `<class 'tuple'>`

Comment: It is not really obvious, but looks like `mypy` fails here because it cannot infer container type properly. You give `Iterable[Any]` - it should produce `T[Any]`. This syntax (generic TypeVar's) is not supported (but hopefully will be at some point), you can try [returns HKT](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some old trial and error I arrived a solution to make mypy happy

change the signature to

```
def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T], container:Callable[[Iterable[T]],Any]=tuple) -> Any:
    return container(islice(iterable,n))
```

but that was actually the last solution I found the first was to make a stub file and make that into its own module if it wasn't already

```
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Iterable

T = TypeVar("T")

@overload
def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[T,...]:...
@overload
def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[Any], container:Callable[[Iterable[Any]],T]) -> T:...
```

but now with

```
@overload
def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[T,...]:...
@overload
def take2(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T], container:Callable[[Iterable[T]],Any]) -> Any:...
```

(it can also be in the main file)

mypy sure is hard to please...